# How to insert Time using Quarkus reactive client?

Tags: java, vert.x, quarkus

I am new to Quarkus and I am trying to insert a record in table but tables contains Time field, and while inserting record Pgpool is not allowing and For that I am using @JsonSerialize.

```
public class Table1{

  private int id;                                                             
  @JsonSerialize(using=JsonTimeSerializer.class)
  private Date scheduleTime;   

     public Uni<Long> addRecords(PgPool client) {
        String sql = "Insert into table1 (runtime) values ($1)";

        Tuple t = Tuple.of(scheduleTime);

        return client.preparedQuery(sql).execute(t).onItem()
            .transform(pgRowSet -> pgRowSet.iterator().next().getLong("id"));
    }
}

public class JsonTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>{
  private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

  @Override
  public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    
    gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    
  }

}
```

Now while executing this I am getting below exception:

> ESTEASY002020: Unhandled asynchronous exception, sending back 500:
> io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Parameter at position[0]
> with class = [java.util.Date] and value = [Thu Jan 01 12:26:26 IST
> 1970] can not be coerced to the expected class = [java.time.LocalTime]
> for encoding.

Could anyone please let me know why this is happening? What is wrong am I doing?

I can achieve this using below way but I want to it to be auto converted using some annotation.

> Object[] array = {scheduleTime.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime()};

Comment: What is the type used in the database? It seems it's time-only (not date and time). In this case, why not use `LocalTime` in your bean instead of a `Date`?

Comment: I am converting application from spring to quarkus, so to change type From Date to LocalTime in bean can cause issue at many places so I want it as it is, as there are many beans with different datatype date, datetime etc.